# Rails twitter-bootstrap-rails glyphicons are not working

Tags: ruby-on-rails, twitter-bootstrap

When using the twitter-bootstrap-rails gem, the glyphicons aren't working. I noticed that the resulting css has:

```
background-image: "/assets/twitter/bootstrap/glyphicons-halflings.png"
```

This isn't a valid css property, so of course it doesn't work. I'm not doing anything special and this is being pulled in directly from the sprites.less file, which has:

```
background-image: @iconSpritePath;
```

I believe this should be translating to a background: url() in the resulting css, but this doesn't seem to be happening.

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
 background-image: asset-url("glyphicons-halflings.png");
```

Comment: Well, the issue is that the sprites.less file is inside of the twitter-bootstrap-rails gem, so I can't modify it...well, I could, but it wouldn't then remain modified when I pushed to prod unless I created a modified version of that gem.

Comment: Don't forget any file you put in the app assets tree will override it's gem equivalent which sits in the vendor tree. So just copy the code into your own file. Put it in the same place in your app assets tree as it is in the gem assets tree. Make your changes. Test. Commit. Push.

Comment: I've tried that, but it seems that the stuff in sprites.less is overriding anything I put in the assets tree. No matter what I do, the background-image from the sprites.less is the one that ends up being used. I'm sure I'm doing something wrong here, but I can't get it to work. It also seems weird that it wouldn't work out of the box with the twitter-bootstrap-rails gem.

Comment: Yes. That's odd. I use the sass bootstrap version for rails, personally.